# Joomla 1.6.3 with the Beez20 template error

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I am running Joomla 1.6.3 with the Beez20 template, and am getting the following error when sending an email from my contact form: -

Language string failed to load: invalid_address: You must provide at least one recipient email address.
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/content/o/p/r/oprins/html/afribam/components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php on line 114

I have an email address in the contact form so not sure why I am getting the error message.
Also my mass mailer is working as well as the "new user registration" is sending confirmation emails

I am hosted with GoDaddy and the domain is in a subfolder

Any Ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after 1.6.3 update the line

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo
$this->contact->id; ?>" />
```

in `/components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_form.php` is missing,
which cause error when sending the contact form.

I inserted it in line 41 and now contact form is working fine.